# How to detect Rowhammer vulnerability?

Tags: exploit, vulnerability, memory, rowhammer

Related to [How to know whether a RAM module is vulnerable to rowhammer before buying?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/96488/1220), how can I check whether my already installed memory modules are susceptible to this attack, without having to use any Windows/Mac-only tools?

There's a [PoC module for detecting Rowhammer](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/project-zero/issues/detail?id=283), but it seems many people have had problems compiling it and the issue has gone cold (no response since October 2015).

Answer (score 8):

The [Exploiting the DRAM rowhammer bug to gain kernel privileges](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/exploiting-dram-rowhammer-bug-to-gain.html) article linked to in [@J.A.K.'s answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/135703/1220) had a link to [Google's `rowhammer-test` program](https://github.com/google/rowhammer-test) for checking for this vulnerability on "Linux or Mac OS X" and "x86-32 or x86-64". It runs indefinitely, stopping only if it detects a bit flip. One [forum post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rowhammer-discuss/i1zya99LC1U) recommends running for at least 30 minutes before considering the RAM safe.

Answer (score 2):

[MemTest86* version 7 has a Rowhammer test](http://www.memtest86.com/features.htm), but it only works on systems with UEFI support.

* not to be confused with MemTest86+.